# How to replace a keyword ONLY if the keyword is on its own and not part of another word?

Tags: javascript

I've the following code which replaces all words in a message that match keywords from an array of objects with an image:

```
        insertEmoticons(message){

            let emotes = [
                {
                    keyword: "LOL",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico"
                }
            ]

            emotes.forEach(emote => {
                message = message.replace(emote.keyword, `<span class="${emote.keyword}"><img src="${emote.url}"></span>`)
            })

            return message

        }
```

So when I write LOL, it gets replace with a `<span class="${emote.keyword}"><img src="${emote.url}"></span>`

Sadly, when LOL is part of another word like oneLOLtwo, LOL gets replaced with an image again, which is not my desired effect. Any way to easily avoid that?

Comment: Search for the word with preceding and succeeding spaces. eg ` LOL `. You probably also want to account for full stops I guess.

Comment: Use regular expressions to identify whether this is a word

Comment: Example: keyword : /\bLOL\b/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use word boundary `\b` regex to figure out if word is preceded or succeeded with words. There is problem with matching the beginning of string so, you can use `(?:^|\\s)`.

```js
function insertEmoticons(message) {
  let emotes = [{
    keyword: "LOL",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico"
  }]
 
  emotes.forEach(emote => {
    message = message.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+ emote.keyword + "\\b", "g"), `<span class="${emote.keyword}"><img src="${emote.url}"></span>`)
  })

  return message
}
console.log(insertEmoticons('oneLOLtwo'));
console.log(insertEmoticons('LOL'));
```

Comment: This fixes my problem but it also create a new one. I only want the word to be replaced if it completely matches the keyword from the array. In this case, both lol, LOL and lOL trigger the replacement. I only want the word to be replaced if it's all caps LOL.

Comment: @Bobimaru Just remove the `i` in the regex options.

Comment: As @Paul pointed, removing `i` solves the issue. I have updated the solution